# what is the best way to get a attrubute value in strings.xml?

Tags: android

Can someone please tell me what's the best way to get the value of an attribute in the strings.xml file? I would like to get the value of "code" in the following:

`<string name="menu_item1" code="5002">Coffee and Muffin</string>`

Comment: if you want to read any res file then use `XmlResourceParser`

Answer (score 2):

"code" is not part of the schema for strings.xml,

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

You aren't going to be able to get it from the android SDK. Perhaps you can explain what you are trying to do with the code, so someone can suggest an alternative approach.